# can not add HTML image tags in QML text with right to left text

Tags: html, qt, qml

in a text with

```
textFormat :TextEdit.RichText
```

when I add a text and images using HTML  it works fine but when the text is not English(it is right to left ) if there is more than one image next to other image, the image is placed on the text(instead of after the text)
I have tried to  add many things like float property in image , adding div around whole the text and setting dir and align parameters ,changing text's horizontalAlignment and changing Text type to TextArea but  it did not help. only when I add a CL RF after this line , the output becomes correct , and I don't know why. this solution doesn't work for more than two images. this code work fine in a separate html in browser.

```
Text{
    id:view
    width: 640
    height: 200
    anchors.top: parent.top;
    textFormat :TextEdit.RichText
    text:"سلام<img src=\"qrc:/assets/20x20/1f44b.png\"><img src=\"qrc:/assets/20x20/1f44b.png\">"
}
```

(actually I want to display emoji in Persian text with original images instead of emoji characters and tried some other solutions and this one was working perfectly with English text)
Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Relevant bug report for anyone that's interested: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66057

Comment: You can use `Row` as a workaround

Comment: @folibis thanks. I checked this solution but this has a similar problem but this time words are written on the images. this is the string I tested  "<tr><td  align=\"right\"><td>یک</td><td>
<img src=\"qrc:/assets/20x20/1f44b.png\"><img src=\"qrc:/assets/20x20/1f44b.png\"></td><td>سلام</td></tr>"